# Android and MoPub integration

Tags: android, mopub

I integrate `MoPub` with `Android`.

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Banner-Integration

But the ads are not displaying, instead of that

```
       Welcome to Mopub!
      Click here to test add
   You can now setup a new campaign for other adds.
```

How can I list ads in my app?  So that it will be clicked it will be counted against my app.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your request to Mopub is being reviewed (there is probably a message in box on Marketplace tab saying so). You should wait for it to be done. However, in my case there wasn't any progress for quite a long time (about 2 weeks) until I asked for that the Mopub support. Once the request is checked you'll get ads.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new account in MoPub, Mopub automatically creates test order with that particular banner:

```
Welcome to Mopub!
Click here to test add
You can now setup a new campaign for other adds.
```

To disable this banner and add your own banners, go to https://app.mopub.com/advertise/orders/ , pause "MoPub Demo Order" and add your own orders and line items.

The system works right after the account was created, you don't need to undergo review to disable test banners or add your own banners.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to test with test ads.
[This](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/test/) link of the MoPub documentation will show you how to use test ad id's to get an ad on every request while developing.

To make things easy for you, this is a often used solution making use of the ternary operator. This says IF development THEN use test ad id ELSE use your production ad id.

```
moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
moPubView.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? "b195f8dd8ded45fe847ad89ed1d016da" : "YOUR_PRODUCTION_BANNER_ID");
```